# jenkins tests with ranorex

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, ranorex

I'm just getting started with Jenkins and I have a few doubts that must be silly, but I'm stuck at it.

1. After I build my project Jenkins save the build file in some specific path?
2. Using Ranorex for automation test, is it better to put my files locally on the server or push them to a repository?

Note: I just start tried to use this, at this moment I can check for changes at BitBucket, build the file, build the Ranorex test and run the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins is quite a versatile application that allows system setup to specific needs and requirements of the test project. So i'd say go with the way that seems most logical/easiest. It's kind of a learning process as well so you will be able to understand the working flow of Jenkins itself.

But to answer your 2 questions:

1) By build files i believe you mean the test reports? - For this I actually use the Jenkins UserContent folder. This requires the "Copy to slave" plugin to be installed. With this you will get an additional Post-build Action where you can specify the files that will be copied over to the UserContent folder. But don't forget to specify a common layout for the naming of report files through the Ranorex run parameters ("/rf"). The UserContent folder actually acts as a web server and you can directly link the URLs for email reports. (eg. "http://Jenkins-server.com/UserContent/Regression-Client-Test-#1.html")

2) This totally depends on the system setup. But i can give you an example on how our system is currently set up. So we have Jenkins which runs on a Linux machine. It is only used to manage and run the tests and the actual machine does not include the automation test project. Then we have the test machine which runs on Windows and holds the actual automation tests. This machine is connected to Jenkins through the Slave functionality. So basically when someone starts a test job Jenkins from the Linux machine sends a command to the slave to start the automated tests. When the test run has finished post-build actions take over and copy the report files from the Slave machine to the Linux machines UserContent folder.

Now when talking about the test project management. It's a good idea to use a gir repository which will add another layer of somewhat "security". But if you have a small team (or you are the only test developer) then there is no actual need for it. You just copy the project to the test machine to a specified folder whenever needed/updated and you are ready to run it.

Regards,
Martin